# Cypress loads wrong page after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

I have my website set to a foreign language so that when Cypress clicks on the contact button or any button with href tag on my website, it should have sent me to the foreign version of that page but instead, it sends me to the english one. I cannot replicate this when I try to do it by hand.

I'm testing my website, salaenrollment.com, to make sure that if I switch the language on the website to a foreign language, it doesn't switch back when I click around to the contact and such.

```
cy.visit('https://salaenrollment.com/')

cy.contains('ភាសាខ្មែរ').click()
  .url().should('include', '/kh')

cy.contains('ទំនាក់ទំនង').should('have.attr', 'href', '/kh/contact')
  .click()
```

Everytime I test it with cypress, the language always switches but when I try to replicate it manually, I can never get it to switch. I wrote the code on cypress as simple as possible and I manually set wait times in the code but nothing works. About 90% of the time, when I test with cypress, the language doesn't switch. There is nothing wrong with the website and there are no errors.

What should happen is that cypress will enter the website, change the language, click on the contact button and the contact page will be in the foreign language. The cypress test should match a manual test.

Comment: Is the language of your site depening on any cookies (geolocation/ browser language) or there sort?

Comment: No, it's no dependent on those

Answer (score 1):

probably you need to add some waiting time because your page its reloaded after switching the language maybe you need to check if your element already appear in the Dom with should('be.visible') this will add some waiting time by trying to check if the element is ready .

```
cy.visit('https://salaenrollment.com/')

cy.contains('ភាសាខ្មែរ').click()
  .url().should('include', '/kh')

cy.contains('ភាសាខ្មែរ').should('be.visible')

cy.contains('ទំនាក់ទំនង').should('have.attr', 'href', '/kh/contact')
  .click()
```

Comment: The wait time doesn't really help. I tried adding the be.visible and it did work the first time, but it never worked again no matter how many times i reload it.

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

your selectors is also wrong please try this (it works in my local setup):

```
 cy.visit('https://salaenrollment.com/')

        cy.get('.language').click()
            .url().should('include', '/kh')

        cy.get('.language').should('be.visible')
        cy.get('.contact ').should('be.visible')

        cy.get('.contact ').should('have.attr', 'href', '/kh/contact')
            .click();
```